# android setAlpha of video which playing in SurfaceView

Tags: android, youtube, surfaceview, alpha

currently I want to make effect like Youtube app on Android.
I want setAlpha of SurfaceView when the video has been minimized and is swiping left/right, just like Youtube App did.
but I found when I setAlpha of the RelativeLayout outside the SurfaceView, the whole Video disappear but the Layout is still visiable!
Also I found a same question
[Android VideoView.setAlpha is not working (Xoom with 3.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535850/android-videoview-setalpha-is-not-working-xoom-with-3-0)
can someone help me please?
thx!

Comment: Please post your code.